# What is the difference between using jQuery and it's alias ($)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When using Jquery a syntax error occured. What is the difference between the two

```
   $.ajax({
   //working
   });
   Jquery.ajax({
   //not work
   });
```

Comment: One word _Nothing_, unless you've another library that uses `$`

Comment: "ReferenceError: Jquery is not defined". But for `jQuery`, jQuery is more-likely to actually be jQuery, and not something else.

Comment: You have mispelled it @SalmanA. It should be jQuery.

Comment: should be **jQuery** and **NOT Jquery**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$ is just an alias/shortcut for the formal name jQuery. This was done by jQuery to reduce the weight of scripts that would depend on the library.

you have misspelled the library identifier in your example:

```
 //Your Example
 JQuery.ajax({
 });

 //What it should look like
 jQuery.ajax({
 });
```

The 2nd code above should work fine like

```
 $.ajax({
 });
```

if in case the dollar sign ($) is also used by other libraries. You can use the `jQuery.noConflict();` to give way to other libaries.

Answer (score 6):

The correct name is `jQuery`, not `Jquery`. `jQuery` and `$` are the same thing. `$` is just a shortcut. Please read the documentation to get more information about how to properly use `jQuery` - https://api.jquery.com/

Answer (score 0):

As the others already point out the problem:-
`jQuery`, not `Jquery` .

The below code from **jQuery Source Code** will show you how `jQuery` sets `$` as **alias** or **shortcut**. And what happens when `jQuery.noConflict` is called.

http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js

```
var
    // Map over jQuery in case of overwrite
    _jQuery = window.jQuery,

    // Map over the $ in case of overwrite
    _$ = window.$;

jQuery.noConflict = function( deep ) {
    if ( window.$ === jQuery ) {
        window.$ = _$;
    }

    if ( deep && window.jQuery === jQuery ) {
        window.jQuery = _jQuery;
    }

    return jQuery;
};

// Expose jQuery and $ identifiers, even in AMD
// (#7102#comment:10, https://github.com/jquery/jquery/pull/557)
// and CommonJS for browser emulators (#13566)
if ( typeof noGlobal === strundefined ) {
    window.jQuery = window.$ = jQuery;
}
```

For learning jQuery refer to :-

- https://api.jquery.com/
- http://learn.jquery.com/